# Load more posts via Ajax WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using load more with ajax for my portfolios and it's working well but I'm having a problem when I am making the portfolio as a front page, the load more isn't working anymore, it displays same posts

This is the code of load more in js

```
var isoElem = jQuery('.masonry-images');
if(isoElem.length > 0) {

    var elem = isoElem[0];
    var iso = new Isotope( elem, {
      itemSelector: '.work-image',
    });
}

var page = 1;
 var loadMorePosts = jQuery('#load-more-posts').text();

  function loadMore() {
    page++;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: './page/' + page,
        beforeSend: function () {
            jQuery('#load-more-posts').html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>");
        },
        complete: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {
            var $data = jQuery(data).find('.single-blog,.work-image');
            if ($data.length > 0) {
                jQuery('#load-more-posts').html(loadMorePosts);
              jQuery('#blog-posts,#portfolio-posts').append($data);

              if(isoElem.length > 0) {
                iso.appended($data);
              }

              $data.css("display", "none");
              $data.fadeIn("slow");
            }
            else {
              jQuery('#load-more-posts').html('No More Posts');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            jQuery('#load-more-posts').html('No More Posts');
        }

    });
}

jQuery('#load-more-posts').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    loadMore();
});
```

You can try here live at ' http://illyrianthemes.com/themes/vicenza/ ' here is not working when I remove as front page of WordPress then works perfectly for example check four columns ' http://illyrianthemes.com/themes/vicenza/four-columns/ '.

Best Regards

Comment: I thought that wordpress handles AJAX calls with admin-ajax.php? I haven't done ajax in wp in some time, but you should localize script and call it in your url along with a function that will get you your posts (in php).

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: The main problem is that isn't working only when I'm making the page as front page, when it is a regular page it's working great.

Comment: Then something with permalinks should be the issue.

Comment: Yea must be something like that, maybe it loads only in dynamics pages not static pages(front page - static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I found the answer if someone needs it.

Instead of doing this:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

do this:

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {

$paged = get_query_var('paged');

} elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {

$paged = get_query_var('page');

} else {

$paged = 1;

 }

query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged ) );
```

Maybe it will help someone.